# Mach-o to Ubuntu Executable for Oracle 10g ProC

Tags: linux, oracle10g, ubuntu-12.04, proc, mach-o

I've got a series of `Unix Executable Files` that I need to convert into a Ubuntu Executable; when running `file <filename>` I'm told that it is a Mach-O 64-bit executable. I am running this on a 64-bit Ubuntu OS.

My question is, is there a way to convert these files to a Linux executable? Failing that does anyone know of somewhere I can source the Linux Oracle 10g ProC executable, as a sneaky way around the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the 10g version? 11g can be downloaded. If you have a product licence (which sounds unlikely as you seem to be trying to use a version you've somehow acquired) you can still get 10g, as described [at the bottom of this page].

Answer (score 0):

I suspect those are compiled for Mac OS X then. If so, then you have a ***very small** chance to run them on your Linux system: try running them through [maloader](https://github.com/shinh/maloader). If that works, be happy. If it doesn't, then it doesn't work because Linux doesn't have the same core system libraries (the so-called "frameworks") that OS X has. In this case, you can't really do anything.